# Перевод foreach с С# на Java

Tags: java, c#

Как можно `foreach (List<Tuple<int, int>> c in coords)` переписать на Java?

Comment: Добавьте немного контекста, пожалуйста. Что именно смущает? `foreach` или `Tuple`? Какой тип у `coords` в обоих языках?

Comment: Лучше весь код показать...... по идее вместо `int` будет `Integer`, притом и у переменных тип должен быть такой же.......но лучше всё же весь код увидеть и узнать что точно нужно

Comment: Скорее всего автор не знает что такое Tuple

Answer (score 2):

В чистой яве аналогов `Tuple` нет. Можно написать свой [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8446411/3212712):

```
public class Pair<K, V> {

    private final K element0;
    private final V element1;

    public static <K, V> Pair<K, V> createPair(K element0, V element1) {
        return new Pair<K, V>(element0, element1);
    }

    public Pair(K element0, V element1) {
        this.element0 = element0;
        this.element1 = element1;
    }

    public K getElement0() {
        return element0;
    }

    public V getElement1() {
        return element1;
    }
}
```

И использовать так:

```
Pair<Integer, String> pair = Pair.createPair(1, "test");
pair.getElement0();
pair.getElement1();
```

---

[Либо](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5303619/3212712) юзать реализацию из AppacheCommons: [Pair](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html)

---

Если ява под андроид используется, то там всё уже есть: `android.support.v4.util.Pair`

---

В любом случае `foreach` будет таков:

```
for (List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> c : coords) {
    //тут c - это List<Pair<Integer, Integer>>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tuple в c# это Кортеж, можете написать свой "кастомный" и использовать как хотите

```
public class Cortege{

  private int first;
  private int second;

  public int GetFirst(){
    return first;
  }

  public int GetSecond(){
    return second;
  }

  public Cortege(int _first, int _second){
    first = _first;
    second = _second;
  }
}
```